Tests failing after migrating Spring Boot from 3.2.5 to 3.3.0
I migrated my Spring Boot application from version 3.2.5 to 3.3.0 and suddenly all my WebMvcTest tests are failing. After some debugging I found that the issue is in a custom OncePerRequestFilter Component that has a @Value("${my.custom.value}") that is not properly populated, while it was populated with version 3.2.5. With version 3.2.5 the property is populated with the value in the application-test.properties, with version 3.3.0 the property is populated with the string ${my.custom.value}. I looked at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.3-Release-Notes but I couldn't spot anything that seems related, any idea?

Show us some code

Did you find the solution for it?

If you want application-test.properties to be applied you'll need to enable the test profile.
I'm not sure why this stopped working, are you setting spring.profiles.active anywhere?
You might need to do something like:
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(
public class MyTest {
   ...
}

See ActiveProfiles
